# Js: Injecting values to multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form with an input field.
I am able to inject a value to the input field, from a `<script>`.
I get that value from a POST request.

But when i try to create another form, with the same input field (same name and id), value injection does not work.

I have not been able to troubleshoot the problem.

This is the html and route handler for the first case:

```
<form role="form" action="/scale" method="POST" id="sc-form-scale">
            <input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit for Scaling">        
</form>


app.post('/scale', function(req, res) {
        
        var myFilePath = req.body.filePath;
        res.redirect('/');
        
        console.log(myFilePath);
        console.log(typeof myFilePath);

        
});
```

And this is for the second case:

```
<form role="form" action="/rotate" method="POST" id="sc-form-rotate">
                <input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath" value="">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit for Rotation">       
</form>

    app.post('/rotate', function(req, res) {
    
        var myFilePath = req.body.filePath;
        res.redirect('/');
    
        
        console.log(myFilePath);
        console.log(typeof myFilePath);
    
    });
```

In the first case, everything works fine.
This is what i get as a console.log output:

```
/home/user1/Desktop/myPart.step
string
```

But this is what i get in the second case:

```
string
```

As you can see, it is recognized as a string, but it's value is blank.

I don't why is that case. The code is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both forms you have have the id `filePath`. Your ids should be unique, though names don't have to be. It sounds like you're setting the value by id, so you should either assign a unique `id` to each one and set them individually, or set them both to have the same class and use `querySelectorAll` or something like that to select multiple elements at once.

For instance, if you assign the class `'filePathClass'` to both inputs, when you want to assign a value, you can do something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.filePathClass').forEach(function (fileInput) {
    fileInput.value = '...';
})
```

Comment: Thank you! But if the id is unique, then how do i assign the value to both the forms?
Should i create two different statements of assignment? One for the one field, and one for the other?

Comment: You can set the value with multiple statements, which should be fine with a few elements, though if there are many elements, you'd probably want to do some sort of group selection, like assigning a class to each element and setting values. See the updated answer.